# How to Set Content-Security-Policy to Allow Img-Src From AWS S3

Tags: html, node.js, express, amazon-s3, content-security-policy

I'm trying to add a functionality to my Node JS app where users can upload an image to an s3 server, and have it appear on the front-end by changing an HTML img source. Everything works in terms of the s3 server, however CSP is blocking my attempts to change the img source. I've tried setting headers on all of my Node/Express responses, and here's the part in my server.js file:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader(
    'X-Content-Security-Policy',
    "default-src 'self'; img-src https://testmaterialsmatter.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Content:*;"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Security-Policy',
    "default-src 'self'; img-src https://testmaterialsmatter.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Content:*;"
  );
  next();
});
```

Also here's the test image's URL: https://testmaterialsmatter.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Content/og-image.png

Only on Chrome does the headers in the developer console seem to actually change, however if I set the default-src to 'none', the content still loads. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CSP does not allow to use `*` in the path-part, so adjust content of the `img-src` directive to the `img-src https://testmaterialsmatter.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Content/;`

Comment: Also `X-Content-Security-Policy` header is obsolete, you can completely delete it.